# Ubuntu WSL2 cannot find example files of GTK3

Tags: gcc, windows-subsystem-for-linux, gtk3

I am learning gtk3 from the [documentation](https://docs.gtk.org/gtk3/getting_started.html) and it works fine until a code has example headers included in it like this:

```
#include "exampleapp.h"
#include "exampleappwin.h"
```

When I compile like the documentation says:

```
gcc `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0` -o gui4 example4.c `pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0`
```

I get this error:

> fatal error: exampleapp.h: No such file or directory

I have installed gtk examples using:

```
sudo apt-get install -y gtk-3-examples
```

Running Ubuntu on WSL2 on Windows. Editor is VSCode. Just using its editor and terminal.
How do I fix this?

Comment: `"exampleapp.h"` (as opposed to `<exampleapp.h>`) would be a local file - while you probably *can* build the examples using gcc directly (adding `-I./` to the include path for example), the instructions for the example code in the page that you linked actually say *"You can build each example separately by using `make` with the Makefile.example file."*

Comment: I tried building them directly. From an online git repository for gtk3 I downloaded the header files and put them in the same folder as example4.c. It gave me a series of undefined references to main, example_app_window etc.
Then I cloned the entire repository and used that example's makefile but it said "make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found."

Comment: I'm really confused here - you shouldn't need to put anything in any folder, just run `make -f Makefile.example`

Comment: Yes I tried that too. Says 'no makefile found'